# Does the integral of this function exists for any real value of $\alpha$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I came across an integral $\int_0^\infty x^\alpha \cos x\, dx.$ Does this integral exists for any real value of $\alpha$?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that, for example, it does *not* exist for $\;\alpha=0\;$ ? What have you done so far in this?

Comment: In which sense exist? Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: If you are curious about Lebesgue integration, see my related question and answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764841/for-what-values-of-alpha-beta-is-x-alpha-sinx-beta-in-l10-1.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  you can only have problems near $0$ or near $\infty$.  Near $0, \cos x \approx 1$, so you can ignore it.  What values of $\alpha$ are trouble?  Near $\infty$, the oscillation of $\cos x$ is a problem, so you need $x^\alpha$ to control that.  What values of $\alpha$ will work for this purpose?  What values of $\alpha$ work at both ends?

Answer (score 0):

HINT 1:

Abel's test can be used to show that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^a}dx$ converges for $0<a$.

HINT 2:

$\int_0^{1}\frac{\cos x}{x^a}dx$ converges for $a<1$